# Trying to write a generic filter function in Scala

Tags: scala

The code that i have written is mentioned below

```
def genericFilter[A,B](f:(A) => B, list:Seq[A]):Seq[B] = {  
  for { x <- list ; if(f(x)!=false) } yield f(x)  
}
```

I'm trying to write the filter function but the output of the function is always yielding a Sequence like

```
Seq[Boolean] = List(true, true)
```

I'm not able to print the values of the list

Comment: Hi @VenkateshPrasadMJ, well the problem is that if your function goes from **A** to **B** and **B** is a `Boolean` then every output will be a `Boolean`. And since you exclude all elements that fail the predicate, the resulting `Seq` will always be filled with `true`s.

Also, Why making **B** a _generic parameter_?, since it is a filter function the result must always be a `Boolean`, if not, how can you check against it?

Comment: try using `yield x` instead of `f(x)` if you want the original values to be, well, yielded.

Comment: Tried that but yield x returns me a type mismatch error
found   : x.type (with underlying type A)
        required: B

Comment: Just change the function signature to `def genericFilter[A,B](f:(A) => Boolean, list:Seq[A]): Seq[A]`

Comment: Hi Luis,

I got it, so how i can i go with my actual goal that is to get the list values by doing a boolean check that is always true.

Comment: def genericFilter[A](f:(A) => Boolean, list:Seq[A]):Seq[A] = {  for{ x <- list ; if(f(x)!=false)}  yield f(x)  }
                                                                                                              ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Boolean
        required: A

Comment: What do you mean with _"always true"_?
If you want to filter values given a predicate your going in the right way, just change the function signature, and yield `x` instead of `f(x)` as @TzachZohar mentioned.
PS: I forgot to remove the generic parameter **B**, which is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot got the list values with above changes. But just a question why didn't B work since i'm declaring it as generic type?

Comment: It's not that **B** didn't work, its is just that you don't need it.
A predicate is something that will always return a `Boolean` value. Also just think, If the result of the function is some arbitrary type **B**, how could you check if it is true or not?
Maybe you're confusing it with the Map function or the Collect function that does a filter and a map in one step.

Answer (score 3):

***More Functional:***
You can use foldRight for traversing the list and filtering based on condition.

```
val l = List.tabulate(10)(_ + 1)
def filter[T](l: List[T])(op: T => Boolean): List[T] = {
  l.foldRight(List[T]())((b, a) => if(op(b)) b :: a else a)
}
filter(l)(_ > 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
    def genericFilter[A](f:(A) => Boolean, list:Seq[A]):Seq[A] = {
    for { x <- list ; if(f(x)) } yield x
  }

println(genericFilter((x:Int)=>x%2==0, Seq(1,2,3,4)))
```

It will print the list containing elements that satisfy function f.

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that **B** isn't used anywhere, so you could _(and should)_ remove it from the signature. Also `if (f(x) != false)` is a code smell, just write `if(f(x))`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot. Appreciate for the quick response :)